# How can i call a modal component from another page

Tags: reactjs

I am having a modal component shown below, which is opening by default because the open state is set to true.

```
 import { Fragment, useRef, useState } from 'react'
    import { Dialog, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
    import { FcApproval,  } from "react-icons/fc";
    
    export default function Modal() {
      const [open, setOpen] = useState(true)
    
      const cancelButtonRef = useRef(null)
    
      return (
        <Transition.Root show={open} as={Fragment}>
          <Dialog as="div" className="fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto" initialFocus={cancelButtonRef}  static onClose={() => null}>
            <div className="flex items-end justify-center min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">
              <Transition.Child
                as={Fragment}
                enter="ease-out duration-300"
                enterFrom="opacity-0"
                enterTo="opacity-100"
                leave="ease-in duration-200"
                leaveFrom="opacity-100"
                leaveTo="opacity-0"
              >
                <Dialog.Overlay className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" />
              </Transition.Child>
    
              <span className="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen" aria-hidden="true">
                &#8203;
              </span>
              <Transition.Child
                as={Fragment}
                enter="ease-out duration-300"
                enterFrom="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
                enterTo="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
                leave="ease-in duration-200"
                leaveFrom="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
                leaveTo="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
              >
                <div className="inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full">
                  <div className="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
                    <div className="sm:flex sm:items-start">
                      <div className="mx-auto flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 rounded-full bg-red-100 sm:mx-0 sm:h-10 sm:w-10">
                     <FcApproval size={100} />
                      </div>
                      <div className="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-0 sm:ml-4 sm:text-left">
                        <Dialog.Title as="h3" className="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">
                          <b>Registered Successfully</b>
                        </Dialog.Title>
                        <div className="mt-2 inline-block">
                          <p className="text-sm text-gray-500">
                            Yayy,Start your shopping
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:px-6 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="w-full inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border- 
                      transparent shadow-sm px-4 py-2 bg-green-600 text-base font-medium text-white 
                      hover:bg-green-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 
                      focus:ring-green-500 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm"
                      onClick={() => setOpen(false)}
                    >
                      Continue
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Transition.Child>
            </div>
          </Dialog>
        </Transition.Root>
      )
    }
```

But when I call a function to trigger the modal component it does not open up the modal.

But when I call a function to trigger the modal component it does not open up the modal.

Example

```
OpenModal.js

export default function openModal() {
  const popModal = () => {
     return <Modal />
   }
  return (
    <div className='App'>
    <button onClick={popModal}>Open Modal</button>     
   </div>
  );
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: There's an unclosed button tag in your JSX in your first example so it is malformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, I cannot exactly point out why your approach is wrong, but it just not how it works. Instead I would do something similar to this:

```
// Some component using your Modal

const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

return (
  <>
   <button onClick={() => setModalVisible(true)}>Open Modal</button>
   {/* Modal accepts visible and onClose props */}
   <Modal visible={modalVisible} onClose={() => setModalVisible(false)}
  </>
)
```

This way you can easily control the state of the modal, in every single component that you're using.

Comment: Alright, Thank for you showing me an easier way to control the modal state. it worked

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck.

Comment: How do you think is the best way to call the modal after dispatching a redux action. so the modal will be triggered without onClick function?

Comment: Then you should move the state to redux. Very similar to what you have now. Move `modalVisible` to redux state, create action that changes this state. And then just dispatch two actions, one for whatever you want, and the other one to open/close modal. Or just simply do: `() => {dispatch(action()); setModalVisible(true);}`

Comment: Thanks you, I just tried your solution and it's perfectly working. cheers